# .net core viewmodel providing route parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a viewmodel class which has a bunch of different route parameters as its properties.

```
public class FiltersVM
{
    public string parmOne {get; set;}
    public string parmTwo {get; set;}
    public string parmThree {get; set;}
    //etc
}
```

On my controller it uses those parameters properly when I send them via their matching name, ex:

```
<a asp-route-parmOne="Hello" asp-route-parmTwo="Dave" asp-action="Index">Link</a>
```

Here is an example of the controller (a portion of it):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(FiltersVM filtersVM, List<string> messages, string searchString)            
{
    //do something with filtersVM.parmOne etc <--This works
}
```

Problem:
When I go from one action to another

```
public async Task<IActionResult> QuickTask(FiltersVM filtersVM, List<string> messages, string searchString)            
{
    //do something with filtersVM.parmOne etc <-- this works

    Return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { filtersVM});
}
```

This sends me back to the Index controller, but it doesn't break the ViewMOdel into its parts for routing.  My URL it returns to looks like this:

```
https://localhost:44398/{ControllerName}?filtersVM=ProjectName.ViewModels.FiltersVM&{other route parameters not included in Viewmodel}
```

So, the second controller is using the VM parameters correctly for doing it's work, but when it finishes and tries to redirect it has the problem.  Any ideas?

I am trying to avoid creating a redirect like this.  I haven't tried it, but i bet it would work, I have a lot of parameters so this is not ideal:

```
Return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { parmOne = filtersVM.parmOne, parmTwo = filtersVM.parmTwo, parmThree = filtersVM.parmThree });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filtersVM` is already an object, so it just

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index),filtersVM);
```

which will correctly serialize each property of the model to a query string.

Note however that the method serializes the properties using `.ToString()` - it will not correctly serialize properties which are complex objects or collections.

Comment: Yes, once you explained it that makes sense.

Comment: Is there any way to submit the model as an input using <input type=hidden asp-route-for-filtersVM=@Model.FiltersVM />   I tried that and it didn't work, but if there is something similar please let me know

Comment: I am running into a problem where if I also try to return a seperate List<string> as a parameter, it causes an error on the above (it clears all the existing paramtrers and has nothing there).  Is there any way to use the model as above but also include extra route parameters?

Comment: Question - Can you route more than just the viewmodel fro the redirecttoaction?  I cannot find a way to do it.  Should I open a new question on SO?

Comment: No. You could include `searchString` in the view model so its serialized, but you cannot include a `List<string>` - to send a `List<T>` in a url, you would need to manually generate `..&[0].messages=someValue&[1].messages=anotherValue&...`

Comment: But doing that is not a good idea - apart from the ugly query string, you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. Best to save the data, just an ID, and then get the data again in the GET method.

Comment: Thanks for the info Stephen.  My original question/issue is fixed and I am working more efficiently with it.  I am combining the View Model on the controller with a Data Dictionary of parameters on the view and using asp-all-route-data